# 5 second delay for OnlyOffice (mono-fastcgi & nginx) on Linux

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, mono

### Setup

Debian 8 (jessie) - fully up to date. Server is in local network, ping <=1ms, bandwith 10..40 Mbit (`bing -s 124 -S 1024 localhost <server>`)

> the server is also running some other webservices, which are idle though.

OnlyOffice v8.1 (which uses ASP.NET)
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.42, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-10)
nginx version: nginx/1.6.2

### Problem

When loading pages, I experience amazingly constant delays of 5sec (+ processing time) [Screenshot of HTTP GET durations & timings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1uEs.jpg)

At least I suspect, that there is some kind of timeout, which I cannot name atm.

### Steps Taken

I've already looked at the following logfiles:

- nginx
- onlyoffice

### Question

- Does anybody have an idea, of what kind of trouble I run into?
- How can I debug my curret setup? (I am unfamiliar with mono-fastcgi / ASP.NET applications)

Comment: The site you linked to is unreachable because their SSL is misconfigured. Try uploading an image here or at imgur.com instead.

Comment: link updated (imgur)  
Michael Hampton: Idk how you come to this conclusion!? (successfully tested my SSL config through various providers... yet imgur upload accepted my URL ^_^)

Comment: In Wireshark I can see that when the browser sends a ClientHello, your server sends back (an unencrypted) 501 Method Not Implemented error and then disconnects. Something is definitely wrong with your setup. [Here is a copy of the pcap file, so you can look at it yourself.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/a4r6aqhy8mula1v/hitzkopf-at.pcapng)

Comment: And I think maybe even more is wrong. Your IPv4 address appears to be hosted at Ortsantennenbau Außerfern GmbH, while your IPv6 address appears to be hosted at 1&1! This is very unusual...

Comment: I disabled SSL on purpose, and solely accept TLS. (Are you forcing SSL?) -- the "Ortsantennenbau" is my ISP (and has no IPv6 yet, imho), "1&1" is my nic. That seems to trigger a weired kind of fallback from "1&1"? || still, would you be able to aid me with the mono-fastcgi problem? (which is on another server, btw)

Comment: Well, you did ask about that. Anybody with IPv6 can't reach your site at all because of this problem. If your server really doesn't have IPv6, I would remove the AAAA record.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I appreciate your info!! - Still idk what's the matter with IPv6, as I don't normally use it (not spread where I live, yet). Still, I have to have a look at this! Which client did you use, and how comes, you're requesting SSL by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is experiencing the same behavior:

[Mono does not yet support "precompiling" sites.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843510/aspnet-compiler-on-mono)
This feature would be used by OnlyOffice, to avoid rendering the whole page on every request, if it was available.

(It should really be obvious, still it took me some time to figure out. Maybe because I'd rather expect this to be called "cache" instead of "precompile")